# Does carrott2 have an adapter for JIRA integration for visualization JIRA ticket collection

Tags: carrot2

Does carrott2 have an adapter for JIRA integration for visualization JIRA ticket collection?  I am trying to makes sense of a significant collection of tickets in our company.  These are likely to belong to a small number of categories that can be deduced from the text content of the tickets.  It would be great if I can point carrot2 to JIRA service and get the foam tree visualization of tickets.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Carrot2 does not have an adapter for JIRA. To cluster JIRA issues you'd have to write a piece of code that would fetch the text from JIRA and submit it to Carrot2 REST API in the format required by Carrot2.